What is the difference between single and double plus in tikz coordinates?
I've been using double plus in TikZ for relative coordinates:
\draw[-] (somecoord) -- ++(1,0);

but I have found TikZ code with single +. What is the difference between ++(dx,dy) and +(dx,dy)?

You can find both descried in the pgfmanual, e.g. here: tikz.dev .

A double + means that the addition is cumulative i.e. affects all subsequent points on the path, whereas a single + does not.
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [blue] (0,0) |- +(1,1) |- +(2,2);
  \draw [red] (1,0) |- ++(1,1) |- ++(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


That is, ++ changes the reference point used to calculate any subsequent relative coordinates on the path, whereas + doesn't do that. If you start at the origin \path (0,0) +(1,1) coordinate (a) +(1,1) coordinate (b); then a and b are both at (1,1).
So the following produces the same output as above because drawing between (a) and (b) is drawing a line from a point to a point, which has little (or no?) visible effect.
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [blue] (0,0) |- +(1,1) |- +(2,2);
  \draw [red] (1,0) |- ++(1,1) |- ++(2,2);  
  \path (0,0) +(1,1) coordinate (a) +(1,1) coordinate (b);
  \draw (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

